# gettext usage for 2 strings that are the same

Tags: python, internationalization, multilingual, gettext

Is there a more compact way if I want 2 keys have the same value? This works:

```
msgid "Next"
msgstr "Pág. seguinte"

msgid "Next page"
msgstr "Pág. seguinte"
```

I could imagine writing it like this instead but is it legal?

```
msgid "Next", "Next page"
msgstr "Pág. seguinte"
```

I have more questions about gettext, what do you recommend? I.e. how to do with html in translations and escape characters.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

i think best option is split words in code like:

```
a = _('next')
b = '%s %s' % ( _('next'), _('page') )
```

and in `.po`

```
msgid "Next"
msgstr "seguinte"
msgid "page"
msgstr "Pág."
```

why you need to translate html special characters ? For example, `&copy;` on all languages ©

Comment: Bad idea. There's no guarantee that "Next" and "Next page" start with the same characters in different languages. That's why you should always localize entire phrases instead of single words.

Comment: Real-life example: You might want to translate "Next" as in "move to the next page of a multi-page wizard" as "Weiter" in German, but you'd translate "Next Page" as "Nächste Seite".

Comment: Thanks! From the info here I know now more. I have msgstr like `msgid "Watches &amp; Jewelry"
msgstr "Montres &amp; Bijoux"` which has escape chars and I also have html in msgstr `msgstr "<a href='/li'>Finn din vara gratis.</a> <a href='/ai'>Annonsera</a> nytt och begagnat från privatpersoner och företag. Jobb, evanemang, möbler, fordon, fastigheter, elektronik, kläder och barnvagnar."` I don't know recommendations for those cases but I will try follow recommendation to translate entire phrases instead of single words.

Comment: You should translate proper English version and escape the result of `ugettext()`. There is no reason to require translators to know all the HTML entities. Also translate each sentence separately (and each `<a/>` text in your case).

Comment: I accept the answer since it is what I'm asking for ("what do you think is the best option")